# How to set up a macro to cast several spells in sequence in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How can I script a macro to my Mage do several sequencial attacks? I've tried the command /castsequence but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 13):

WoW's macro system is deliberately unable to cast multiple spells with a single keypress except in very specific circumstances; this is to discourage botting/cheating.  Blizzard's approach to macros (in-game or out) is that one keypress should trigger only one action.

The only case in which multiple spells/items can be used in a single macro is when only the last one triggers the global cooldown.  This means that a warlock could macro [Soulburn](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=74434) and [Summon Felhunter](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=691) together (because Soulburn doesn't trigger the GCD), but not [Bane of Agony](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=980) and [Corruption](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=172).  If you have many spells or items which don't trigger the GCD, you can even chain them together, as in the (in)famous [PoM/Pyro](http://www.wowpedia.org/Useful_macros_for_mages#The_I_Win_Button) macro for mages.

If you want to cast multiple GCD-causing spells with the same macro, you *can* use `/castsequence` to do it, but you'll need to hit the macro once for each spell.  This can still provide plenty of flexibility even for fairly complex cast sequences, especially when combined with other macro commands and conditionals.  I thoroughly recommend Wowpedia's page on [Making a macro](http://www.wowpedia.org/Making_a_macro) for learning how to create powerful macros.

Comment: Just to add, castsequence casts spells in order every time you press the macro. So for example, /castsequence Fireball, Frostbolt will alternate between fireball and frostbolt each time you hit it. It does not cast them one after each other.

Answer (score 3):

You can't script several actions to occur automatically on a single mouse click or key press.

The closest you can do is a `/castsequence`, bind your macro to an action bar button or a hotkey and press it repeatedly to advance through the sequence of actions you set up.

Comment: Can you show me? An example?

Comment: "/castsequence Frostboalt, Fire Blast" Doesnt works

Comment: Well, for one thing, you'd have to spell frostbolt properly.

Comment: @EdPichler That's it, but as LessPop said, you might want to check your spelling.